# Play first keyframe only once / queue animations

Tags: css, animation

I've written the following bit of CSS:

```
    .bulb--off { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
}

.bulb--on { 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    left:rem(1);
    right:0;
    opacity:0;
} 
.bulb--on { 
    opacity:0.4;
    animation-name: bulbFlicker;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes bulbFlicker {
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
    25%  { opacity: 0.9; }
    50%  { opacity: 0.95; }
    75%  { opacity: 0.9; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

What I hope to happen here is that the bulb would fade from off (opacity:0) to on (opacity:1) and then flicker.

What actually happens is that the bulb jumps from off to on (no fade) and then starts flickering, clearly what is happening is that when the animation starts it begins keyframe 1 as it should. I've tried adding a transition on opacity so that when it starts keyframe 1 it fades to it but it seems to ignore that property. Is there a way I can chain animations or even only make it play the first keyframe once?

I think I can do this using javascript but I've managed to get this far using CSS only and ideally I'd like it to remain CSS only.

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: Check this tutorials; http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-on-off-button/

Comment: @NaeemShaikh unfortunately not with imagery as it's under an NDA. I'll try to knock one together with placeholder divs instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alexward1981/96e3ve65/3/ I'd like the first frame to fade in rather than just flick on but then I want it to only do the slight flicker and never go back to opacity:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply **two animations** and add a delay to the second one equal to the length of the first animation you get the played first effect.

```css
.light {
  -webkit-animation: fade 3s;
  animation: fade 3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.light .bulb {
  -webkit-animation: jitter 1s infinite;
  animation: jitter 1s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes jitter {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes jitter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/*Meaningless stuff for it to look cool*/

.bulb {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 85%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 85%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.metal {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
}
.pole {
  margin-left: 17.5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="light">
  <div class="bulb"></div>
  <div class="metal"></div>
  <div class="pole"></div>
</div>
```